# Should I Use rbenv or RVM for RubyMine

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, rubymine, rbenv

OS X 10.11.5. I'm learning Ruby and followed [Ryan Bigg's post](http://ryanbigg.com/2015/06/mac-os-x-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you/) to install Ruby and Rails using `chruby` and `ruby-install`. After using vim for a few small programs I looked for a more productive environment. I installed [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) and like it, but [RubyMine doesn't support chruby](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14086). JetBrains tech support recommends I use `rbenv/RVM`.

I selected `chruby` because the blog post didn't have `sudo`. I'm new to OS X and don't yet understand `sudo` and [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection).

Should I use `rbenv` or `RVM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` is just a command that executes the command following it as root.  This results in files created by those commands being owned by root, and being uneditable and undeletable by your user account.

*rvm* vs. *rbenv* is a matter of personal preference -- my preference is rvm.  I find it very easy to use and rich in functionality.  You don't need to install it using sudo -- in fact, I prefer not to.  It will install everything in a ~/.rvm directory, and requires some minor modification to your startup scripts, which it can usually do automatically as part of the installation.  Google `install rvm` for clear instructions about how to install it.

Comment: I have been leaning towards rvm as I research. Good to know it doesn't require sudo. In a nutshell, under SIP sudo does not work for standard users without running `sudo visudo` as an admin, and the warnings of the consequences of messing up are scary to a newbie.